# React Native : TextInput loosing text when style changes

Tags: react-native

I have a TextInput whose style changes according to a state.

```
<TextInput
            autoCapitalize="characters"
            defaultValue={this.props.name}
            onChangeText={(text) => { this.handleChangeText(text); }}
            onEndEditing={this.handleTextSubmit}
            placeholder={this.props.dictionary.Identification__placeholder}
            placeholderTextColor={color.WHITE}
            ref={(component) => { this.textInput = component; }}
            style={[
              defaultStyles.input,
              styles.input,
              this.state.keyboardIsVisible && styles.inputSelected,
            ]}
            underlineColorAndroid="rgba(0,0,0,0)"
          />
```

The problem is that when the style changes, it erases the current value in the TextInput. Is there a way to fix this behavior ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is handleTextChange doing? you should have a `value` property like `value={this.state.inputText}` and have handleTextChange update that value.

Comment: handleTextChange updates the value in the state. `value={this.state.inputText}` solved my problem. Thank you, I didn't tought of doing this.